# UITableView Search For Name In Object

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to search through an array of objects that are retrieved from Parse to display the results in a `UITableView`. I tried using the same method that I used in one of my other apps, but in that case it was just searching through an array of strings.

This is my code at the moment:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: NSString) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF beginswith[cd] %@", searchText) //Use either contains or beginswith
    searchResults = DataManager.sharedInstance.rideArray.name.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out a solution to the problem. The property that I want to search for within the 'Ride' object is name.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `rideArray` is an array of Parse objects that have a property `name`, the predicate should be

```
NSPredicate(format: "name beginswith[cd] %@", searchText)
```

And you filter the array with

```
rideArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on the second line - '[Ride]' does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'. Any ideas?

Comment: Cast to `NSArray`. `(rideArray as NSArray).filtered...`

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!